# Javascript assigning the return value of a Callback function to global variable

Tags: javascript, callback

My question is about Javascript.
I have a Callback function which receives a Position object on a successful callback.

The problem is that when I try to set the properties of the Position object to a global variable at a successful callback it just does not let me do it and the global just remains undefined.

As a workaround to that instead of directly setting the object properties to global variables i'm trying to return it through the callback function but I couldn't find a way to set the return value of the callback function to a global variable.

Here's the simplified code.

```
var x;

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);

//on Successful callback receives a Position Object
function onSuccess(position) {  
  var coords = position.coords;  
    x=coords;       // Setting directly to an object does not work x still remains undefined after succesful callback               
return coord; // Trying to set this to a global object 

}

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't return a value from the callback (in this case). That would mean that inside of `getCurrentPosition`, the return value from the callback has to be assigned somewhere.

Assigning it to a global variable works, but at the time you access that variable, it was not assigned the new value yet. E.g.

```
// x is assigned in `onSuccess`
var x;
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
alert(x); // will be undefined, the response is not processed yet
```

Think about it: `getCurrentPosition` is probably doing an Ajax request to get the position. Such a request takes (a) time (couple of milliseconds) and because of that (b) is *asynchronous*, which means that JavaScript *does not wait* until the response is received. Your code is *way* faster. `onSuccess` was not called yet when you alert `x`.

**Only solution:**

All the code that has to access the position as to be in or called from the callback.

Comment: actually good point, my answer is a stupid oversight on my part. the code isn't linear so you'd need to do whatever you want to do with the coords in the callback, to ensure the value has been bound

Comment: You are actually right.The getCurrentPosition function is trying to get the geolocation which is asynchronous that's why when i try to access it from the global variable it's probably not set and returning undefined.Isnt there way to assign the variable to return value after the async function is done with it's job?

Comment: @Torukojin: No, where should to value be returned to? As said, the code runs asynchronously. That's why the value is passed as a parameter to the callback function so that you can use it and do whatever you want with it. If it were possible to `return` the value, then  `getCurrentPosition` would do it. But it is not, hence you have provide a callback. Maybe you'll find [this article](http://felix-kling.de/blog/2011/01/14/how-to-return-data-from-an-ajax-call/) helpful to understand the problem (but I'm not that good in writing ;))

Answer (score 2):

As described by Felix King, you cannot return a value from a callback and in your global variable variant, the variable will not be set until after the AJAX request completes and calls the callback (hence its name !).

Using a global variable you can solve your problem if you have some sort of processing loop, you can add this code to that loop to do what is required whenever the coord changes.

```
  if (coord) // global variable has a new value
    // process it
     alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    // then clear it
    coord = null;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting it via the global `window` object?

```
//on Successful callback receives a Position Object
function onSuccess(position) {  
  var coords = position.coords;  
    window.x=coords;       // Setting directly to an object does not work x still remains undefined after succesful callback               
return coord; // Trying to set this to a global object 

}
```

also, since you return the coordinates from the success handler, is there not another way to get this value?

Answer (score 0):

put a `console.log(x);` just after `x=cords` to check the value (works on Chrome and FF with FireBug)

do that also just after the call of OnSuccess.

Also don't forget that there is asynchronous code in JS (if you use AJAX to get the position), maybe you just don't receive the answer when you check the value of `x`

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a helper method like flowing:

```
var LocationHelper = function() {};

LocationHelper.prototype.getLocation = function(callback) {

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);

    function onSuccess(pos) {
        callback({
            pos: pos
        });
    }

    function onError(message) {
        callback({
            message: message
        });
    }

  };
```