# How to know when the new value is assigned to global variable in callback function (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, callback, global-variables

Is there any trick to know when the new value is assigned to global variable in callback function in JavaScript.
As I read in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189492/javascript-assigning-the-return-value-of-a-callback-function-to-global-variable),it is asynchronous , so JavaScript does not wait until the response is received.
I need the new value in my Java code which run JavaScript code in my html page.

Comment: No, but if you already have a callback, then why would you need to "watch" the new value? Just do whatever you need to do inside the callback function itself.

Comment: I need the value in my java application, so I want to return the value which is assigned during callback in a method.

Answer (score 0):

There is no trick because you can't write code the way you're trying to write it.  You do not want to put the data into a global variable and then try to magically discover when the data is there.  That's just not a good way to write async code.

Instead, you need to put the code that uses the result of the async call in the actual callback itself or call some function from the callback and pass it the data.

---

You don't show your actual code, but here's an example using jQuery Ajax (just for example purposes, you can do this with any code or library):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" },
  success: function(data) {
      // the results of the ajax call are here in the data argument 
      //    to this callback function
      // you can either use the data here (write any code here that needs to use it)
      // or you can call some other function and pass it the data
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that needs to access that variable has to be within the callback; else the variable would not have been assigned the value yet.

So you need to trigger the Java code from within the callback.  Tough to provide an answer on how to do that without more information.

```
var callbackFunction = function(arg, callback) {
    if ('an error') {
        callback(new Error('error text'));
    }
    else {
        // set the global variable
        callback(null, 'result');
    }
};

var callingFunction = function() {
    callbackFunction('arg', function(err, result) {
       if (!err) {
           // Global variable is set
           // Trigger call to Java
       }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no direct possibility.

One possible solution is implementing an observer-pattern or using something like [backbone](http://backbonejs.org/), where models trigger events for changes of state.

Another possible solution is, working with [futures or promises](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises). [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) gives a possible approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can define yor global variable as object instanse:

```
var globalVar = { 
                  _val: null, 
                  changed: function () { 
                    alert(1); 
                  }, 
                  setValue: function(val) { 
                    _val = val; this.changed(); 
                  }, 
                  getValue: function() { 
                    return _val; 
                  } 
                };
```

Use setValue and getValue to set and get a value of ur global variable:

```
globalVar.setValue(45); // will set the value and throw an alert box. 
globalVar.getValue(); // will return 45
```

So u can just init 'changed' prop with ur own function and it will be fired if 'setValue' called