# Variable value is undefined in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the user location by using HTML5 geolocation. The lat and lng value are received successfully and I can show it on the map. I want to save the user location to use it later so I defined origin variable and I concatenated the lat and lng variables and then I assigned the concatenated value to origin. When I am trying to use the origin value later its value is undifined. Could someone please tell me when the problem is in the code. I guess the problem is very silly but I cannot solve it. I don't think the problem is related to variable scope.

Here is the code:

```
let map ;

// initialize the map and show it on the dashboard.
function initMap() 
{
    // Map options.
    let options =
    {
        center :
        {
            lat : 41.015137,
            lng : 28.979530
        },
        zoom : 12
    }

    // New map.
    map  = new google.maps.Map
    (
        document.getElementById('map'),
        options
    );
};

$(document).ready
(
    function()
    {
        $("#order_and_show").click
        (
            function()
            {
                // Change the text of the title and the button when get order from the user. 
                $('#order_title').text('Cancel the order right now') ;
                $('#order_and_show').text('Cancel Now') ;

                // Get user location from browser using HTML geolocation.
                let origin ;

                // HTML5 geolocation.
                if (navigator.geolocation) 
                {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition
                    (
                        function(position) 
                        {
                            let pos = 
                            {
                                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                                lng: position.coords.longitude
                            } ;

origin = position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude ;

                            // Add marker.
                            let marker = new google.maps.Marker
                            (
                                {
                                    position : pos,
                                    map : map,
                                }
                            ) ;

                            // Center the map according to user location.
                            map.setCenter(pos);

                            // Add popup window for user location information
                            let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow
                            (
                                {
                                    content : '<h6>Your Location</h6>'
                                }
                            ) ;

                            marker.addListener
                            (
                                'click', 
                                () =>
                                {
                                    infoWindow.open(map, marker) ;
                                }
                            ) ;
                        }, 
                        function() 
                        {
                            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
                        }
                    );
                } 

                else 
                {
                    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
                    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
                }

                // Handle Geolocation errors.
                function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) 
                {
                    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);

                    infoWindow.setContent
                    (
                        browserHasGeolocation ? 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' : 'Error: Your browser does not support geolocation.'
                    ) ;

                    infoWindow.open(map);
                }

                console.log(origin) ;


            }
        ) ;


    }   
) ;
```

Comment: the problem is the scope of variable, use var instead of let. more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11444416/2996989)

Comment: Thanks @AhmedSunny the link you referred was so helpful. But I cannot see the wrong in my code.

Comment: try one thing, console out origin right after concatenation,  if  its undefined there then its concat issue,

Comment: I tried to console out origin right after concatenation and I got the right value.

Comment: The problem is that you try to access `origin` outside the callback. When you do that the callback hasn't been executed yet thus `origin` is still `undefined`. Do all work related to `origin` inside the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` callback. Set `origin` to a promise that you resolve in the callback. Allowing you to work with promise callbacks/async await methods later on. I suggest taking a look at: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your current code is that you try to access `origin` outside of the callback that sets it. The `getCurrentPosition` callback is probably executed asynchronously, thus when you try to access `origin` outside of the callback the callback function is not yet executed resulting in a `origin` value of `undefined`. You could use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) or [`async`/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to solve this issue. Such a solution might look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map"),
    { center: { lat: 41.015137, lng: 28.979530 }, zoom: 12 }
  );

  function handleLocationError(infoWindow, msg) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(map.getCenter());
    infoWindow.setContent(msg);
    infoWindow.open(map);
 }

  $("#order_and_show").click(async function () {
    // notice the async keyword ^
    $('#order_title').text('Cancel the order right now');
    $('#order_and_show').text('Cancel Now');

    let position, origin;
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      try {
        // await the position before continuing
        position = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject);
        });
        let pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        origin = position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude;
        let marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: pos, map: map});
        let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: '<h6>Your Location</h6>'
        });

        map.setCenter(position);
        marker.addListener('click', () => infoWindow.open(map, marker));
      } catch (error) {
        // I'm not sure how you are able to access infoWindow here since it's
        // created in the try block after the error is thrown.
         handleLocationError(infoWindow, 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.')
      }
    } else {
      // Same here, you don't have access to infoWindow, since it's not created
      // yet. However both the above and this are present to mimic the question
      // structure.
      handleLocationError(infoWindow, 'Error: Your browser does not support geolocation.');
    }

    // origin should be available unless geolocation isn't supported or
    // getCurrentPosisiton failed to execute successfully
    console.log(origin);
  });
});
```

For more info about working with asynchronous behaviour I recommend checking out the [MDN Using Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) guide.

Comment: You are right I try to access origin outside of the callback that sets it.
The same problem has already discussed here:[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189492/javascript-assigning-the-return-value-of-a-callback-function-to-global-variable]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think problem seems to be with this line:

```
 let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   content: "<h6>Your Location</h6>"
 });
```

You have declared `infoWindow` using `let` keyword which is why I think it is scoped within `function(position) { .. }` block and which is why `infoWindow` is being passed to `handleLocationError` function. The same could be said for `let pos` variable. declaring your variables globally could solve the problem.

declare `pos, marker and infoWindow` varibles in the same line `let origin;` like so:

`let origin, pos, marker, infoWindow;`

Final Code Should look like this, hope it helps:

```
let map;

// initialize the map and show it on the dashboard.
function initMap() {
  // Map options.
  let options = {
    center: {
      lat: 41.015137,
      lng: 28.97953
    },
    zoom: 12
  };

  // New map.
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#order_and_show").click(function() {
    // Change the text of the title and the button when get order from the user.
    $("#order_title").text("Cancel the order right now");
    $("#order_and_show").text("Cancel Now");

    // Get user location from browser using HTML geolocation.
    let origin, pos, marker, infoWindow;

    // HTML5 geolocation.
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        function(position) {
          pos = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
          };

          origin = position.coords.latitude + position.coords.longitude;

          // Add marker.
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pos,
            map: map
          });

          // Center the map according to user location.
          map.setCenter(pos);

          // Add popup window for user location information
          infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "<h6>Your Location</h6>"
          });

          marker.addListener("click", () => {
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
        },
        function() {
          handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }
      );
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }

    // Handle Geolocation errors.
    function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
      infoWindow.setPosition(pos);

      infoWindow.setContent(
        browserHasGeolocation
          ? "Error: The Geolocation service failed."
          : "Error: Your browser does not support geolocation."
      );

      infoWindow.open(map);
    }

    console.log(origin);
  });
});
```

Comment: there are no problems with pos, marker and infoWindow  variables the problem I faced that the value of origin variable is undifined. I tried as you said to declare the origin variable as global variable but that did not solve my problem.

Comment: the code segment you mentioned works fine. there is no problem with it.

Comment: I doubt that `handleLocationError` function will have access to `infoWindow and pos` in future.